# How to do text processing on 2nd row of csv and append specific processed row result to new column in CSV using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

```
filename~contenturl~uuid~nodeid~contentid

000224.pdf~store://2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin~d6203724-1100-4057-9ed5-4ca6a94f5512~1324625~1363256
000238.pdf~store://2018/7/20/11/35/4302b390-1134-424d-a92f-ad27b233e8c1.bin~96b7343d-349d-4316-8bc6-def5bd924032~1324641~1363292
000262.pdf~store://2018/7/20/11/35/5ff59679-b3ec-46d2-aa7d-5ec28eff6fe9.bin~11827eee-67bb-43b7-a743-966514f26457~1324661~1363375
```

The above is my .csv file is there with separator as "~" , I want to do substring operation on the second column which is starting from store:// 
and want to add checksum result of that row to a new column in the same CSV if possible.

e.g.

```
filename~contenturl~checksum
000224.pdf  /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin  23423423425
```

So if you see the end result, I substring and process path in store:// and added a new column of that file called checksum.

I want this via shell script using bin/bash

=======================
As far as I am newbie, I just tried with AWK and able to get only first and second column values using

```
awk -F "~" '{print $1, $2}'  $csv_file
```

Now the next thing is complex for me,
Second column values requires text processing and **checksum** you can get via

```
cksum /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin
```

Yes you heard right,
final result would looks like

```
filename~contenturl~checksum
000224.pdf  /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin  23423423425
```

rest of other column would be better if we would have, or else above three column is also fine.
**Note: If it is easy to retain existing column and to add more column named "checksum" that is also fine.**

Comment: What have you done so far, where are you stuck? You need to show some initiative on your own.

Comment: How would you get or calculate the checksum? Your sample output uses `~` as separator in the heading and `  ` in the data line. You state you "want to add checksum result of that row to new column in same csv if possible", but in your sample output you replaced columns `uuid~nodeid~contentid` with `checksum` instead of adding a column. Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: Ok as of now, I am able to just get second column using awk (awk -F "~" '{print $1, $2}'  $csv_file)  for getting checksum there is command  cksum <my second column value which is full path to .bin file>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the solution a bit easier and because your header lines are not consistent (newline in input file and wrong separator `~` in output file), let's assume your input file doesn't contain a header line.

You can solve the task in two steps:

1. Create a `checksums.csv` file, we only need the path the the file:

   ```
   awk -F'~' '{ system("cksum /opt/xyz"substr($2,8)) }' file.csv > checksums.csv
   ```

   The `substr($2,8)` removes prefix `store:/` and `/opt/xyz` is prepended to complete the path. The `system(…)` command executes the `cksum` command on given path and the output is redirected to the output file.

   An example output would look like this:

   ```
   $ cat checksums.csv
   128361894 41 /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin
   820470222 41 /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/4302b390-1134-424d-a92f-ad27b233e8c1.bin
   1593587341 41 /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/5ff59679-b3ec-46d2-aa7d-5ec28eff6fe9.bin
   ```

   Since the output contains three columns checksum, byte count and path, we need to extract columns three and one in the next step.
2. Print the header line and merge column1 (filename) of `file.csv` with column3 (path) and column1 (checksum) of `checksums.csv`.

   ```
   { echo "filename contenturl checksum";\
     paste -d ' ' <(awk -F'~' '{ print $1 }' file.csv) <(awk '{ print $3,$1 }' checksums.csv);\
   } > newfile.csv
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   $ cat newfile.csv
   filename contenturl checksum
   000224.pdf /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/3f176f4b-41a0-4ac4-a795-a2240ffbb7b9.bin 128361894
   000238.pdf /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/4302b390-1134-424d-a92f-ad27b233e8c1.bin 820470222
   000262.pdf /opt/xyz/2018/7/20/11/35/5ff59679-b3ec-46d2-aa7d-5ec28eff6fe9.bin 1593587341
   ```

   Afterwards, clean up:

   ```
   rm checksums.csv
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, It is really awesome and faster solution, seems awk do operation in RAM itself. **Thanks Again**

Comment: Hi @Freddy,This solution works well but we have one more issue in it,
`filename contenturl checksum
filename /opt/alfkofaxprd/alfresco-kofax-source/alfresco-kofax/alf_data/contentstore/2018/12/4/8/48/a922a5ee-7f93-4c2a-887b-97c29c916cb7.bin 1938377259`


if you see filename after header print also filename instead real file name.. and thus at last I am also getting row like below
`187242.pdf /opt/alfkofaxprd/alfresco-kofax-source/alfresco-kofax/alf_data/contentstore/2019/8/26/10/50/d74b942f-16fe-44ff-9fc7-434658f846ed.bin 931825045
187244.pdf`

what changes could be made here in awk?

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue here is I am not able to do proper formatting like asking a question. My Point here is whole row is shifted down in result generated, and header is printed in second row. **if you see my above output I pasted in formatting it include header in first row and in second row first cell include "filename" instead actual filename**.

Comment: check screenshot at [link](https://gofile.io/?c=In6bDw) you will get idea what is issue......

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand what you mean. I tested my solution with your original file and got strange output. The thing is that you have to remove the original header from your CSV file and any empty lines. When both files `file.csv` and `checksums.csv` are `paste`d together, they must have the same amount of lines, i.e. the columns of the first line are merged, then the columns of the second line and so on.

Comment: If there is only one header line (no following newlines), you could replace the first `awk` command with `<(awk -F'~' '(NR==1){next}{print $1}' file.csv)`. The `(NR==1){next}` skips the first line in `file.csv`. Or if you want to skip two lines (your example has one header and one newline), use `NR<3` instead.

Comment: agreed, but ideally it is replicating on new file, so it should automatically same right?  `awk -F'~' '{ system("cksum /opt/xyz"substr($2,8)) }' file.csv > checksums.csv`  This will create new checksums.csv  based on file.csv

Comment: Yes, but if file.csv has a header line for which of course no checksum exists, then the command will complain for the first line, but checksums.csv ends up having one less line than file.csv. And in the next step the lines of both files don't match. Remove the header line from file.csv or try the modified `awk` command from my last comment and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` has the `e` flag for the `s` command allowing you to integrate shell processing like `cksum` in your script:

```
sed -E 'h;s_.*~store:/([^~]*).*_cksum /opt/xyz\1_e;x;G;s_~[^~]*(.*)\n(.*) .* (.*)_~\2~\3\1_;s/~/  /g'
```

- option `-E` switches to extended regular expressions for better readability
- `h` saves the current line in the hold space, so we are free to mess it up
- `s_.*~store:/([^~]*).*_cksum /opt/xyz\1_e` matches everything including `store:/` (to be removed), the filename inside the `()` to be reused as `\1` and the rest of the line (to be removed) and replaces it by `cksum` + path. Now the `e` flag comes to action to execute this command and replace the pattern space with what is returned
- `x;G` exchanges hold and pattern space and then appends hold to pattern space, so the buffer contains
- `s_~[^~]*(.*)\n(.*) .* (.*)_~\2~\3\1_` may be had to read, but easy to write: `~[^~]*` is the second field, `(.*)\n` the rest of the original line and `(.*) .* (.*)` the three fields that are returned by `cksum`, so the second field gets replaced by the file name and the checksum
- You don't write it in your question, but in the example you don't have `~` as delimiter, but two spaces: `s/~/  /g`